# Portfolio functionality is missing in Jira new interface

Tags: jira, portfolio

I'm currently in front this interface but I can't find a way to create a portfolio.

I'm new to Jira and probably missing a simple thing. \"
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkKUv.png)

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Missing information? ok. -----------> I'm using a web Jira software. I'm not the admin, but I have administrator permissions. anything else?

Comment: Is [Jira Portfolio plugin](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/portfolio) installed?

Comment: It wasn't installed, I haven't realized it is a plugin, I thought it was a default integrated service. in the end it was a simple thing, thank you Stefano! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's post it as an answer.

Portfolio functionality is missing in Jira new interface because Jira Portfolio plugin is not installed.